# Using dplyr mutate in an rhandsontable Shiny environment

Tags: r, dplyr, shiny, rhandsontable

I'm getting started with creating a Shiny app that uses rhandsontable. While I have other inputs that I'll incorporate, I just want to complete this first: Use dplyr mutate to sum the values of a row (aside from one column). I'm having trouble doing this.

Here's my code:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  rHandsontableOutput("table")
)

server <- function(input, output){
  df <- data.frame(Category = c("cat_1", 
                                "cat_2", "cat_3", 
                                "cat_4"),
                   Subsection_1 = c(rep(3,4)),
                   Subsection_2 = c(rep(3,4)),
                   Subsection_3 = c(3, 0, 3, 3),
                   Total = c(rep(3,4)))
  values <- reactiveValues(data = df)
  output$table <- renderRHandsontable({rhandsontable(values$data)})
  
  observeEvent(input$table$changes$changes, {
    values$data <- hot_to_r(input$table)
    values$data <- data %>% mutate(Total, 
            Total = rowSums(select(., -c(cat_1,Total))))
  })
}
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

So I'm trying to sum up the rows, excluding cat_1. I've seen some questions posted about using filter, but I haven't seen much on other dplyr functions.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Try `mutate(Total = rowSums(select(., -c(cat_1,Total))))`

Comment: Great, thanks, @YBS. I changed it to what you suggested and piped “values$data” rather than just “data.” So it looks like this: values$data <- values$data %>% mutate(Total = rowSums(., -c(cat_1, Total))))